# Facebook Registration Plugin?

Tags: php, facebook, plugins, registration

How would I take the results of the Facebook Registration Plugin and email it to myself?

Comment: if i want to store this data in database, it is legal?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should post what you have got so far..anyway, as described in the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration):

> The data is passed to your application
>   as a signed request. The
>   signed_request parameter is a simple
>   way to make sure that the data you're
>   receiving is the actual data sent by
>   Facebook.

So you need to specify the `redirect_uri` and then process/extract the data you want from the `signed_request` and email it with the method you are using. How to process the data is described in the bottom of the document I linked above:

```
<?php
define('FACEBOOK_APP_ID', 'your_app_id');
define('FACEBOOK_SECRET', 'your_app_secret');

function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
  list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

  // decode the data
  $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
  $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

  if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
    error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
    return null;
  }

  // check sig
  $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
  if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
    error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
    return null;
  }

  return $data;
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
    return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}

if ($_REQUEST) {
  echo '<p>signed_request contents:</p>';
  $response = parse_signed_request($_REQUEST['signed_request'], 
                                   FACEBOOK_SECRET);
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($response);
  echo '</pre>';
} else {
  echo '$_REQUEST is empty';
}
?>
```

So instead of the `print_r` and `echo` functions, send the fields you want!